# Are Shadar-Kai official in D&D 5e and which supplement can they be found in?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, elf, shadar-kai

I saw [this post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123463/shadar-kai-and-shadow-elves-in-5e) which states that the Shadar-Kai are now an official elf subrace in 5e, but all the online references I could find were for previous editions, UA, or homebrew.

Can anyone tell me if they're actually official, and if so which supplement made them so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Sea Elves and the Shadar-kai, originally published as playtest material in this [Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-ElfSubraces.pdf), were officially released today (May 29, 2018) as part of *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*; the Eladrin elf subrace was included as well. The Avariel and Grugach, as far as I know, were not released.

(The book was officially released today, [according to the product entry on the WotC site](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/mordenkainens-tome-foes). However, it was actually released earlier on DNDBeyond, and the [limited-edition alternative cover versions were available on May 18 in local game stores](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/mordenkainens-tome-foes).)

Note that almost everything from the UA release was modified, including the attribute they get, the cantrip (no cantrip any more, a resistance instead) and the Blessing of the Raven Queen was also relevantly modified. So, if you want to play the actual official version, don't expect the UA version to be any close to it.

Comment: Today's the official release date, according to [the product entry on the WotC site](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/mordenkainens-tome-foes), but they were released earlier on DNDBeyond, and the limited-edition [alternative cover versions were available on May 18 in local game stores](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/mordenkainens-tome-foes).

Comment: Thanks, checked it out in my FLGS.  They’re decidedly more “meh” than I was expecting.  I much prefer the new version of Eladrin.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are official. You can find them in Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes. You can also watch Jeremy Crawford describing them [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYou87fg1f0).